# How can I move my broken Plone content to a new contenttype?

Tags: migration, plone

The "old" content type is: collective.fhdirectory
The "new" content type is: collective.teamdirectory

All the "old" content on my website is now broken…

Answer (score 1):

There is a products that specifically do this job:
[Products.contentmigration](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.contentmigration).

Here a good howto on how to [Migrate Custom AT Types with Products.contentmigration](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/migrate-custom-types-with-products.contentmigration).